# I can't generate on Android Studio(Kotlin) the file BuildConfig of my project

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

I tried to clean project, rebuild, sync project with gradle files, but it doesn't work.

I'm using:
AGP 8.1.0
Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1.

Is there a command to force the generation of BuildConfig?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved it!

First go to build.gradle(Module:app) and look for buildFeatures

You have to write inside of buildFeatures --> buildConfig = true

as i writed below:

```
buildFeatures {
        compose true
        buildConfig = true
    }
```

Then clean project, make project and now you have your BuildConfig generated!

Comment: wow this is new. what is compose for?